# Objective-C access class inside class method

Tags: objective-c, metaprogramming

When inside an instance method, I can refer to the instance's class via `[self class]`, so I don't have to write `[MyClass class]` explicitly.

How would I achieve the equivalent inside a class method? There is obviously no `self` defined in that context...

Comment: Yes, `self` exists in a class context, and it's precisely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`self` *is* defined inside a class method, but it refers to the class itself rather than to an instance of the class. So, in a class method, just use `self` instead of `[self class]`.

Comment: yeah... right... shame on me, just found out I had en error somewhere else that led to me not noticing that fact. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a self a Class method. It will return the Class of highest inheritance.